# How to have sections in android

Tags: android

I want to have sections i.e. at least a bar kind of thing that separates 2 logical parts. On top I have edittext fields and bottom I have textview. I need some separator in between. How to do that? Please note that both edittext and textview are in different rows of the same tablelayout.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You need to provide pictures of what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding View with required `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` you can construct line accordingly with different thickness.
If you want to separate two views with a line which is horizontal then follow snippet will help you out:

Horizontal Line:

```
<EditText/>

<View
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:background="@android:color/black" />

<TextView/>
```

Vertical Line:

```
<EditText/>

<View
 android:layout_width="1dp"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/black" />

<TextView/>
```

As far your table kinda case is concerned:

```
 <TableLayout>
       <TableRow>
            <EditText/>
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
            <View/>
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
            <TextView/>
       </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```